Disable ACLs for S3 buckets in Virtuozzo
I have an S3 environment which is hosted by Virtuozzo, but it implements the aws API. All the things I hit it with like boto3, s3cmd and aws s3api work just fine.
I'm trying to achieve the following functionality for buckets:

I have two aws user accounts, the admin and the guest, and a bucket created by the admin user
The admin should have full control over that bucket
The guest can only upload and read objects from a bucket, but cannot overwrite or delete existing objects, even if he uploaded them.

I've quickly seen that ACLs are not fine grained enough to achieve this, and therefore tried with policies.
I ended with something like this policy:
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<guest_user_id>:user/test.guest" }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
            "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<guest_user_id>:user/test.guest" }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["s3:DeleteObject", "s3:PutObject"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-metadata-directive": "REPLACE"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<guest_user_id>:user/test.guest" }
        }
    ]
}

I quickly realized my policy was completely ignored and the test.guest user had no rights in the bucket. I read here and here and understood that if ACLs are enabled, policies are somewhat overwritten:

ACLs no longer affect access permissions to your bucket. As a result, access control for your data is based on policies, such as IAM policies, S3 bucket policies, VPC endpoint policies, and Organizations SCPs.

Also, from what I tested with both policies and ACLs in place, policies are ignored and ACLs rule.
I've read here that in order to disable ACLs I need to set "Bucket owner enforced setting for S3 Object Ownership". I quickly stumbled upon this command for AWS CLI command, as you couldn't do it with s3cmd . Finally, after running it as it's explained in the Examples section of the article, the bucket still had no Policy Statuses and policies were still ignored (i.e. the guest user had no rights):
aws --endpoint-url=https://<my-endpoint> s3api get-bucket-policy-status --bucket <bucket-name> 
{
    "PolicyStatus": {}
}

Moreover, I've seen that default options for new buckets should have ObjectOwnership=BucketOwnerEnforced by default, but this is obviously not the case for my endpoint. The admin web interface for Virtuozzo doesn't really have any options in this direction.
And this is where my boss told me to give up and do something more useful. I'd like to know though what I did wrong, just to know for the future. I'm also wondering if my endpoint is at fault and actually it's not behaving as an S3 server would.

You said that you have an S3 environment which is not hosted by Amazon, so presumably you mean that you are not working with the real S3. Which S3-like service are you working with? And do you know for sure that it supports the relevant bucket policy and ACL features of S3? Otherwise some of your doc references aren't relevant.

@jarmod I have Virtuozzo. Here are some the docs about it. Both ACLs are policies are mentioned, but I've seen no reference for changing bucket ownership controls, so I'm a bit unsure about that one.

IAM is what controls access to S3, and it is not part of the S3 service or (arguably) API - they're part of IAM. You cannot apply AWS IAM knowledge/concepts other providers. Your question is specific to the provider you're using - include the full details about it, as the answer depends on how they're implementing access controls

Buckets are private by default, so you should never need to use a Deny policy unless permissions were granted by another policy that you want to override. For example, perhaps the Admins group has been granted access to all buckets, but there is an HR bucket that you don't want them to access. You could use Deny to achieve this.
In general, a Bucket Policy should only be used for:

Granting public (anonymous) access, or
Granting cross-account access

To grant permission to a group of users (eg Admin) or to specific users, it is better to grant the permissions via a policy on the IAM User or IAM Group (without using a Bucket Policy).
ACLs are best avoided because they are confusing and limited in scope. You should be able to meet your security goals via IAM policies instead.

Thanks! I will look into IAM policies then.
I have two small questions though.
What is cross-account access?
And as ACLs are best avoided and since my S3 server has them enabled by default, are my attempts of trying to turn them off any good?

Cross-account access (at least in AWS) is when you have a Bucket in AWS Account-A and you want to grant access to the Bucket to entities in AWS Account-B. Thus, access is "cross-account".
